# Cómo resolver este error previsualizando un reporte en JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

Pasa que el programa compila todo bien pero al momento de ir al preview aparece el mensaje de `Xalan Xpath selection failed` y la verdad no encuentro una solución al inconveniente.

Si alguno ha tenido algún problema similar espero me pueda dar una ayuda :c

[image: IMAGEN DEL ERROR]

Comment: El error parece indicar que hay una expresión mal escrita en tu reporte. Revisa las expresiones que tienes en él. En cuanto a la pregunta, es mejor que agregues el texto completo del mensaje de error y no una captura de pantalla, dificulta más la lectura, sobre todo en dispositivos móviles.

Comment: El error está en que construiste mal una expresión y la compilación del XML que define el reporte, arroja un error. Sin conocer el reporte, es imposible saber qué falla exactamente